# Why does underscore use immediately invoked function expression to wrap all of its code?

Tags: javascript, function, object, underscore.js

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="underscore.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I saw that whenever an html is loaded, all the code in underscore.js (even the code we don't need) will be executed because of immediately invoked function expression. Is it a flaw of underscore.js? why don't we wrap all code of underscore.js inside an normal object instead of an function object (the immediately invoked function expression) ?

Comment: You clearly don't understand either the purpose or the result of IIFE

Comment: that is the reason why I asked this question @JaromandaX

Answer (score 1):

It is a common pattern so that they can control what the export. The `.call(this)` may put it on `window` or Node's `global`.

As for "all the code ... will be executed" - the functions won't be executed, but they will be parsed like all other scripts.

Comment: thank you, I got it. So is there any way for an object to actively bind to another object like the way a function bind to windown object or Node's global?
(sorry, I cannot tag your name)

Comment: @MrCold use `_.noConflict()`.